# Coinbase spot price SSL Error: does not support SSL at Request

Tags: javascript, bitcoin, coinbase-api

I am making ab API call to coinbase using the example coinbase supplied but I get `Error: SSL Error: https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/spot does not support SSL at Request`

`npm install coinbase`
`var Client = require('coinbase').Client;`

```
var btcClient = new Client({
  'apiKey': '...',
  'apiSecret': '...',
  'version': '2010-04-20'
});

var currencyCode = 'USD';

btcClient.getSpotPrice({
  'currency': currencyCode
}, function(err, price) {
  console.log('Current bitcoin price in ' + currencyCode + ': ' + price.data.amount);
});
```

The call is made and I am able to catch the error.
Calling the api directly work fine:

https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/spot?date=2017-01-01

albeit with a missing_version warning

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ahh,

I needed to add **'strictSSL': false** to the new client:

```
var btcClient = new Client({
  'apiKey': '...',
  'apiSecret': '...',
  'version': '2010-04-20',
  'strictSSL': false
});
```